# Redirect domain to launch page and access site via /beta extention

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain, launch

I have a site that is in beta mode that I also have a LaunchRock page setup for. I need to set it up so that mydomain.com points to the launch page (signup.mydomain.com) but still displays mydomain.com. But then I need to still be able to access the beta site by visiting mydomain.com/beta without the site being move from it's current directory. Is there any way of accomplishing this via Apache .htaccess Redirect?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` hopes to be your friend here, if you put the following `.htaccess` file in the document root (or better place it in the apache config file, or the `conf.d` directory if your installation has one - if you have write access there).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !^/beta
RewriteRule (.*) http://signup.mydomain.com/$1 [P]
```

How is it supposed to work?

The first line activates rewriting (might not be needed if already on).

The next line defines a condition: if the path of the url starts with `/beta`, do not apply the rule on the next line. (`^/beta` is the regular expression, and the `!` in front of it means to apply if not matching.)

The last line first say to match "everything" that comes in and send it to `http://signup.mydomain.com/`, appended by whatever came in. The `[P]` says to "proxy" it, that is the apache itself will request the url and send the resonse it gets to the browser, so the url in the browser does not change.

**Caveat:** this only works, if the apache itself can connect to `http://signup.mydomain.com/`. This sometimes does not work, especially if this domain is on the same server.

RTFM for more information:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get your first requirement working myself without actually redirecting, until I saw Clemens' answer about proxying, so I've incorporated it in here.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect to signup.mydomain.com if not requesting /beta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/beta(/|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !beta=true
RewriteRule (.*) http://signup.mydomain.com/$1 [P]

#Strip /beta and append beta=true query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beta
RewriteRule beta(.*) $1?beta=true [QSA]
```

This basically strips /beta from your query and appends a beta=true query to whatever your query string is. It then checks for this new query string on the second time through.

If you use beta=true somewhere in your program, just change this to something else.